# Scrapy is not returning any data after a certain level of div

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website : https://www.firstpost.com/search/sachin-tendulkar 
steps followed : 
a. fetch("https://www.firstpost.com/search/sachin-tendulkar")
b. view(response) --> everything is working as expected till this point.
Once i start to extract the data with the below syntax I am able to only get divs upto certain levels
response.xpath('//div[@id="results"]').extract()
after this div i am not able to access any other divs and its content.

I haven't faced this kind of issue in past when developing crawler for other website.. is the issue site specific..?
Can you please let me know a way to crawl the internal divs?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on "not able to access any other divs and its content"? Do you get any error?

I can access all the div's and their content. For ex. the main content of the search result is inside the div - gsc-expansionArea which can be accessed via

```
//div[class="gsc-expansionArea"]
```

and this can give you an iterable to work.

Only the first result is outside this div which can be accessed via another div

```
//div[class="gsc-webResult gsc-result"]
```

And the last sibling of this `//div[class="gcsc-branding"]` has no search results in it.

Comment: Yes, the first content is inside div - gsc-expansionArea but when I am extracting its content its returning empty array.
>>> response.xpath('//div[class="gsc-expansionArea"]').extract()
[]